# Not properly checking if the value exists in a array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Calling the functions

```
$user->setError("h", "h", "error");
$user->setError("h2", "h", "error");`
```

the function:

```
public function setError($title, $msg, $type) {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['messages'])) {
            $_SESSION['messages'][] = array("title" => $title, "message" => $msg, "type" => $type);
        } else {
            $key = array_search($title, $_SESSION['messages']);
            if($_SESSION['messages'][$key]['title'] !== $title)
                $_SESSION['messages'][] = array("title" => $title, "message" => $msg, "type" => $type);
        }
    }
```

For some reason it keeps adding on to the array, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: change `array_search($title, $_SESSION['messages']);` to `array_search($title, array_column($_SESSION['messages'], 'title'));`

Answer (score 0):

Every time function call it will store new values into $_SESSION['messages'][] one after other, if you don't want to add values then you have to clear(empty) array before insertion of new value.
   public function setError($title, $msg, $type) {
   $_SESSION['messages'] = array();
   .
   .
   }

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` works with single dimensional array, to make it work with multi-dimensional array you need to use `array_column` in `array_search` function. `array_colum` will have two parameters array and column name which you want to search.
In your case the code will be as follow:

```
public function setError($title, $msg, $type) {
   if(!isset($_SESSION['messages'])) {
        $_SESSION['messages'][] = array("title" => $title, "message" => $msg, "type" => $type);
   } else {
        $key = array_search($title, array_column($_SESSION['messages'], 'title'));
        if($_SESSION['messages'][$key]['title'] !== $title)
            $_SESSION['messages'][] = array("title" => $title, "message" => $msg, "type" => $type);
        }
}
```